# Capistrano 3 の標準のタスクのソースはどこにありますか？

Tags: ruby-on-rails, github, capistrano

Capistrano3の標準で用意されているタスク、
例えば`deploy:symlink:release`のソースを確認したかったのですがどこにあるのかわかりませんでした。

Github上で検索してみたところ `invoke 'deploy:symlink:release'`と呼び出しているところはあるのですが定義箇所が見つかりません。

https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=symlink

どこでソースを参照できるのでしょうか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/blob/master/lib/capistrano/tasks/deploy.rake

Rakeタスクだと思うのですが、
上記ファイルの84行目ではないでしょうか。

`master`へのリンクなので、今後内容が変わることを考慮して、引用します。

```
namespace :symlink do
  desc 'Symlink release to current'
  task :release do
    on release_roles :all do
      tmp_current_path = release_path.parent.join(current_path.basename)
      execute :ln, '-s', release_path, tmp_current_path
      execute :mv, tmp_current_path, current_path.parent
    end
  end
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。Githubの検索はファイル内でヒットした文字列のはじめの2件までしか表示しないようですね。

Comment: なるほどです。悩まれていた理由がわかりました。確かに一定行までしか表示しないみたいですね。https://help.github.com/articles/searching-code/ も見ましたが改善方法は見当たりませんでした。ちょっと不便ですね。。手元にソースコードがあるなら、そこで`grep`なり`ack`を使うのが良いかもしれませんね。

Comment: はい、次回からは`git clone`してから探すことにします。ありがとうございました。